# Sidebar items disappeared

Tags: mac, finder, filesystem

My finder sidebar items have all disappeared apart from Google Drive, network and my laptop disk...

Everything else has gone e.g. desktop, downloads, applications etc etc. I have been into Finder preferences and all items are checked and cannot work out what is going on...

Any help appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have collapsed all favorite items. Simply hover right next to `favorites`, until a small arrow appears. Click on it and all selected items in the settings should fold out.[image: GIF animation that shows how to (un)collapse items]